# addthis causing console error for twitter

Tags: javascript, twitter, addthis

I am working in some legacy code trying to resolve some console errors. I'm not very familiar with the library or the code. The original issue was because we were loading a dependency over http instead of https.

This is the original code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#username=addthis&domready=1"></script>
```

That gives the error "This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#username=addthis&domready=1"></script>
```

With that I get an obscure error I cannot find any reference too.
[image: The error I get]

I once saw it come up with the file location of "platform.twitter.com/js/tfw/hub/client.js" which is why I think it is related to twitter.

I've tried changing around the url more, but I everything just causes this error every time.

Comment: Its because of the *https* , all in or nothing...

Comment: Ok.. How? The error seems unrelated to https.

Comment: because its not https, the library ( or a part of it) is not loaded, causing some non existing functions...

Comment: According to [this post](https://addthis.desk.com/customer/en/portal/articles/381224-https-ssl-support) the https url I have is correct though.